# loss of precision when assigning to a variable

Tags: java

i had a doubt in assigning or casting to a proper data type.

```
byte a=3;   //compiled
byte b=5;   //compiled
byte c=a+b; //not compiled and reporting as possible loss of precision.
```

here first two statements are compiling even though we are assigning int literal to byte.but what about third statement i am doing the same as above and that too value of a+b is in the range of byte .why there is such error?

Comment: click the check mark when someone answers your question correctly.

Comment: Visit your previous questions, and if someone has offered an answer that really answers your question, click on the green check mark to indicate you accept their answer.  Suggest reading the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: byte a = 3;   //compiled
byte b = 5;   //compiled
byte c = (byte)(a + b); //compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that you can not use assignment to narrow an integer to a byte, because that is an unsafe narrowing conversion (most ints *don't* fit in a byte).  Specifically, none of the allowed [assignment conversions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#184206) may narrow.

However, there is an [exception](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190806) specifically for this case:

> A narrowing primitive conversion may
>   be used if the type of the variable is
>   byte, short, or char, and the value of
>   the constant expression is
>   representable in the type of the
>   variable.

This applies to `a` and `b`.  The type of both variables is `byte`, and the values of both constant expressions clearly fit in a byte.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen sorry i didn't get you can i get elaborate answer

Comment: byte d=200 //this will show me possible loss of precision. how can this will agree to your statement

Comment: @satheesh, as I said, one of the conditions is that "the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable".  200 will not fit in a byte.  Remember that `byte` is signed and 2's complement in Java, so the maximum value is 127.

Comment: then what about the third statement

Comment: @satheesh, `a + b` is not a "constant expression".

Answer (score 2):

When you do the `+` operation on two bytes, they get implicitly converted to an `int`, so the result is an `int` as well. Therefore, you need another cast.

( The literal assignments in the first statement have nothing to do with it. )

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  3 and 5 are `int` literals

Comment: even in first two statements the literal that is assigned to byte variables is an int.then where the third statement differs from the above two

Comment: @Matthew Heh, first i didn't understand your comment, but I tried to answer why the last one didn't work, whereas you answered why the first two do work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that addition performs [binary numeric promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#170983), so a and b are being promoted to ints in the third statement.